# 2D Top down scrolling in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, scroll

I want to make a 2D top down shooter, that can scroll in all directions. However, since I am a beginner at XNA, I have only been able to implement a cursor, player(With movement), and Bullets that rotate towards my cursor. I have been trying to find a way to implement top down scrolling in XNA but i have no clue. One article that I saw on the internet was quite vague and did not help me much. I would also like to make sure that when I move, the objects around me stay in place, so that if I scroll far enough they disappear from sight. I don't want all objects to have this behavior though, as I would like to have the Cursor to always be on screen and not be affected by my movement.

Also, if possible, I would like to have a minimap that would work with this.

I am sorry if I am asking a lot, It's just that I am not familiar with these kind of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article helped me when I faced the same problem:

[XNA 2D Camera](http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/)

On the minimap part:
You would need to think of a design style for your minimap. One way is to draw rectangles for walls based on the position of the walls in the "real" game-world and dots for NPCs. There are tons of examples on how to do these on the internet though if you don't want to mess with this yourself.

**Example**

Say you have a grid-based top down game.

Your player sees 30x30 blocks while the world is 300x300 blocks. You could draw for example 60x60 blocks into a corner of your screen as the minimap using a 120x120 rectangle size (in pixels) so each block could be drawn as 4 pixels.

Now you only need to know which 30 blocks are on either side of your player. If you know on what block the player currently is. You could do (in a grid based game):

```
// We assume that we created a World class that can get a block based on
// a Vector2D.
var playerBlock = World.GetBlockByPosition(player.Position);

// Set the TopLeft position of the minimap accordingly.
Vector2 minimapTopLeft = new Vector(500, 100);

// Draw each 4 pixel block from that TopLeft position (of minimap).
for (int i = -30; i <= 30; i++)
{
    for (int j = -30; j <= 30; j++)
    {
        // Make sure World.GetBlock doesn't return null.
        // Offset the location with the player's location (playerBlock).
        int blockType = World.GetBlock(playerBlock.X + i, playerBlock.Y + j).Type;

        // Draw the 4 pixel blocks based on the i and j vars and the 
        // minimapTopLeft as offset.
        switch (blockType)
        {
            case 1:
                // Draw dirt.
                break;
            case 2:
                // Etc.
                break;
            default:
                // Draw default black block.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will give you an idea on how you could do it. I recommend searching the internet for more examples.

Comment: I like your idea, but unfortunately I do not know how to implement a grid in my game. Do you know any helpful tutorials?

Comment: Don't know the best one. But search for "XNA 2D tile-based tutorial". It basically involves keeping a 2 dimensional array containing your level/world.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is instead of moving the character you keep him in the centre and move everything else in the opposite direction and then factor that offset into your collision checks and whatnot. Think of adding the offset onto objects coords as converting them from screen coords to map coords.